# Apply a blur gradient

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I need to mask an image with a blur gradient.

In more detail; I want the picture to start on the left with no blur at all and on its right to be blurred. The blurring will start to occur somewhere half way. I already managed to blur the image in full but as a separate image, but how do I apply a semi-transparent gradient of that blurring?

```
UIImageView *bluredImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
bluredImgView.frame = frame;
CAGradientLayer *lay = [CAGradientLayer layer];
lay.frame = bluredImgView.bounds;
lay.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite: 0.0 alpha: 0.0] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite: 1.0 alpha: 1.0] CGColor], nil];
lay.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
lay.endPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.0f);
bluredImgView.layer.mask = lay;
[_profileImageView addSubview:bluredImgView];
```

Comment: check out this sample project http://adcdownload.apple.com/wwdc_2013/wwdc_2013_sample_code/ios_uiimageeffects.zip

Answer (score 5):

This question is rather old but still.. None of the previous answers combined the blur effect to a gradient.

This adds the effect from bottom to top (looks cool for title images):

```
titleImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: titleImage];


UIBlurEffect *effect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
UIVisualEffectView *view = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:effect];
view.frame = titleImage.frame;

UIImageView *bluredImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:_location.titleImage]];
bluredImgView.frame = _titleImage.frame;
CAGradientLayer *lay = [CAGradientLayer layer];
lay.frame = bluredImgView.bounds;
lay.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite: 0.0 alpha: 0.0] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite: 0.0 alpha: 1.0] CGColor], nil];
lay.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
lay.endPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 1.0f);
view.layer.mask = lay;
[titleImage addSubview:view];
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the blurred image as a separate layer on top of your image view's layer. Then create a `CAGradientLayer` and add it as a mask layer on your blurred image layer.

Comment: I edited my question.. This is what i tried but failed.. can you please appoint me to the right direction? thanks..

Comment: Dunno. I tried something quite similar and it worked perfectly:

Answer (score 2):

Use code below:

```
NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0] CGColor], (__bridge id)[[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:1] CGColor], nil];

CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
[gradientLayer setFrame:[bluredImgView bounds]];
[gradientLayer setColors:colors];
[gradientLayer setStartPoint:CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f)];
[gradientLayer setEndPoint:CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.0f)];

bluredImgView.layer.mask = gradientLayer;
```